# Background color is crazy during the load

Tags: javascript, html, css

And thanks to every one, this place is the best I know on the internet.

I have a problem with my web site : [test_web_site](http://julien.fslhome.org/CODE/contact.php)

Well actually it does this crazy thing only on mozilla... I've tried on Chrome and IE and they seem to be ok.
On some pages, when it's loading the background appears black, then white and finaly the big image arrives. 
PLUS, some displays changes : font, layout, even text color go crazy during the load time.

What is completly weird, is that for example my navigation text color get blue although it is normaly black... and I have no blue attribute in my css.

I have 4 style sheats (style, desktop, 1000px and mobile) I took my template from html5up... and I must confess there's some stuffs I don't understand...
But I've try to had this

```
body:not(.loaded) #slider img 
{
  display:none;
}
```

after putting this on my body :

```
<body onload="document.body.className += ' loaded';">
```

Idea I found on the internet, but unfortunatly doesn't change anything.

If you have idea of where the problem can come from I really thank you.

Comment: Firefox 37.0.2 (Mac OS Mavericks) -- rendering is ok!

Comment: That is just your site being loaded in. You can make your `body` a different `background-color` so it's not just white. As far as the blue problem, the general / standard color for links is blue, so it just loads it n as the general first. Do you perhaps have a **[css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) in your CSS? This will stop it from loading general/standard web styles.

Comment: V 37.0.2 on Windows 7 is also ok.

Comment: Its working fine in firefox in windows 7

Comment: links are blue by default, so what your seeing is normal before the CSS loads.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's a good new if it works fine for you.
I have to figure out what's the problem on my FF.
I've changed the color of my background but even if I set it to red, these black and white color appear before my image.. and no red either. And about the CSS reset, I've put the code you showd me, but nothing changes...

Comment: Ok thanks dandavis. I see I have no solution to get rid of this ugly blue...

Comment: Don't worry too much about how the site looks as it loads. That's just how the web works.